# How to show Image in Home Screen Widget using Service in API 22?

Tags: android, widget

i create a widget that contain several ImageView and one TextView. when run it in emulator with API 22 the "Problem Loading Widget" message are appear. However it work properly in API upper than 22.
i test it with android studio emulator and genymotion but it's same result.

> widget_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_updating"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minWidth="320dp"
android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:resizeMode="vertical"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0">
</appwidget-provider>
```

> widget.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_widget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
  <ImageView
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/imgDot"
    android:src="@drawable/dot"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgHour2"
    android:src="@drawable/no_0"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgDot"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgDot"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgHour1"
    android:src="@drawable/no_0"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgHour2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgHour2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMin1"
    android:src="@drawable/no_0"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgDot"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgDot"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMin2"
    android:src="@drawable/no_0"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgMin1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgMin1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

> UpdateService.java

```
 public class UpdateService extends Service {

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startMyOwnForeground();
    }
 }

 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String time = getCurrentDateTime();

    RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_updating);
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_widget, time);
    view.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgHour1,R.drawable.no_2);
    view.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgHour2,R.drawable.no_2);
    view.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgMin1,R.drawable.no_4);
    view.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgMin2,R.drawable.no_7);
    view.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgDot,R.drawable.dot);
    ComponentName theWidget = new ComponentName(this, UpdatingWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    manager.updateAppWidget(theWidget, view);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
 }

 private String getCurrentDateTime() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    String strHour, strMin;
    strHour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + String.valueOf(hour);
    strMin = (minute < 10 ? "0" : "") + String.valueOf(minute);

    return strHour + ":" + strMin;
 }

 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
 private void startMyOwnForeground() {
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp";
    String channelName = "My Background Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
   }
 }
```

How can i fix this Problem?
NOTE: i have problem with ImageViews. without it's my widget work fine.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but for what it's worth I came across this also and I ended up replacing `android:src` with `app:srcCompat` in the ImageView components.

I'm using SVG/Vector drawable's and found that I would get "Problem Loading Widget" on API 23 if not using `app:srcCompat`.